# Operator :: OCaml

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, ocamlyacc

I am a beginner in OCaml and trying to build a parser, I want to have a list that stores all the methods in my class. This is one part that I have in my .mly file.

```
init_method_list: 
    { [] }
    | method_list method_decl { List.rev($1) }
;

method_list:
    method_decl { [ $1 ] }
    | method_list method_decl { $2 :: $1 }
;
```

Can anyone explain exactly what's going on here? Especially the :: operation. Been googling around but couldn't find the operator in the docs.

I get that the list can be empty, or we make right recursive calls to fill it up with all the methods in class. `method_decl` just looks for the match of the specific token combinations that represents a method.

Comment: prepend `$2` and `$1`?

Comment: In Ocaml, the operator `::` is use to concatenate an element of type `'a` to a list of type `'a list`.

Comment: okay thanks, does it prepend the element to the front of the list? @alifirat

Comment: What did you google for? I just googled "ocaml tutorial" and on the first hit there's the basic tutorial which uses "::"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the operator `::` is use to concatenate an element of type `'a` to a list of type `'a list`. A little example :

`1 :: [2;3]` produces the list `[1;2;3]` so yes it prepend the element to the front of the list.

Comment: The `::` is not really an operator but rather a syntactic notation – this why it is allowed to appear in matching patterns while operators are not.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else said, :: concatenates an element onto a list of the same type. As just an extra aside, if you need to concatenate two lists, you can use the @ symbol, for example:

[1;2;3]@[4] will give the list [1;2;3;4]